# An easy bulletproof technique to check if the system has jre (windows)

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Sorry my newbie question :P If I promp "java -version" in the cmd on a windows system, am I *guaranteed* that the system will be able to run .jar files *if I don't get any error*?

Comment: If it works (using "java.exe", not just "java") you can reasonably assume there is a JVM installed; but if it doesn't that doesn't mean that there's not, only that java.exe is not on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only guaranteed way to check for a JRE is to try to run a small Java program.

Or maybe not even that - I suppose conceivably a system could have only part of the Java standard library installed, in which case a small test JAR might work fine but a full program might not. Although I can't imagine why anyone would go to the trouble of setting a system up that way.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a reasonable technique.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line you should be able to invoke "java --version" which will return an error if java is not installed or the currently installed version information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run a small class file, which write a value to a file which you then check?  If it fails, it doesn't work.

A good value might be the value of the java.version system property.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can check the registry at HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in. From there, each subkey is an installed JRE.

**edit** Here is C# code that will return an array of strings with the installed JRE's

```
public string[] GetInstalledJavas() {
        // hold the registry subkeys that list the installed JRE's
        string[] jres = null;
        try {
            RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
            myKey = myKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in"); // read-only
            jres = myKey.GetSubKeyNames();
        } catch (Exception myException) {
            Console.Writeline(myException.ToString());
        }
        return jres;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously not. You can put an empty file called java.bat anywhare in PATH, like C:\Windows\System32. Invoking "java" will not yield any errors but it doesn't mean there's a JRE installed.

Comment: Thanks.. guess I'll have to keep looking :) You have any technique to check if jre is installed from any code or command promp?

Comment: As David said, the only "bulletproof" way is by running a small Java program. Also, you can try parsing the output of "java -version". It wouldn't be 100% idiot-safe, but I suppose it would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually suggest, if you're only concerned about checking on windows machines, checking the registry for a handler for JNLP... that should guarantee the presence of a relatively recent JRE.